# Prevent Django from querying for ForeignKey options for every form in ModelFormSet

Tags: django, django-forms, django-database

I'm building a csv import form for my Django application and want to display the to-be-imported rows in a `ModelFormSet` for validational purposes.

Therefore I added a view to the relevant `ModelAdmin` which reads the lines from the csv and prints a `ModelFormSet(queryset=an_empty_queryset, initial={data_from_the_csv})`.

The problem is that the model references three other models via `ForeignKey` fields and for **each field in each form** in the formset a database query is issued in order to populate the `ModelChoiceField`'s options.

Why doesn't Django cache the form (as it is used several times) or is there already a way to accomplish this I don't know about yet?

Comment: django1.5 has model memory cache.

Comment: You're right (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/releases/1.5/#caching-of-related-model-instances), but unfortunately it doesn't affect this problem.

Comment: I've made a little hack to solve this problem : http://stackoverflow.com/a/43105646/8450

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Django formsets just delegate all the details of form creation to the form objects themselves, and the individual form instances aren't aware of the others, so it isn't unexpected that each will have to query for its own choices.

Caching could also have unintended side effects--for example, the form's `__init__` function could be dependent on the `initial` data it received, making the cached `form` object incorrect.

The best way to reduce the number of queries would be to retrieve the choice querysets once and then pass them to your form classes in their constructor.  This will require defining a custom `ModelForm` and a custom `ModelFormSet`.

Your form will need a constructor that accepts the choices directly:

```
from django.forms.models import ModelForm

class MyForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, my_field_choices=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['my_field'].choices = my_field_choices
```

And your formset will need to override a method to run the querysets and pass them into the forms as they're constructed:

```
from django.forms.models import BaseModelFormSet

class MyFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):
    def _construct_forms(self):
        # instantiate all the forms and put them in self.forms
        self.forms = []

        # Define each of your choices querysets
        my_field_choices = Model.object.filter(...)

        #Add your querysets to a dict to pass to the form
        form_defaults = {'my_field_choices': my_field_choices, }

        for i in xrange(min(self.total_form_count(), self.absolute_max)):
            self.forms.append(self._construct_form(i, **form_defaults))
```

(see [the Django source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/formsets.py) to look into how this would work)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. Your solution is what I had in mind, but now I know that this is the way to go!

Comment: I used this solution for the same problem, but when saving I'm getting "Cannot assign "u'7'": "Stop.city" must be a "City" instance." Stop is the ModelForm (used to build formset) that has City fk. Is there any way you can pass around it?, seems like it's to much overhead to go further this way.

Comment: @mariodev, I think you may need to post some more code to help explain/track down the issue.  There probably isn't enough room in comments to do this justice, so it's probably more suitable to its own question.