# modelformset_factory foreignkey triggers database query

Tags: django

My model has a foreignkey:

```
class Status(models.Model):
    status_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name="Status Code")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name="Description")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s - %s" % (self.status_code, self.description)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s - %s" % (self.status_code, self.description)

class PickUp(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, verbose_name="Name")
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, verbose_name="Status", default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

This is my (abbreviated) view:

```
def index(request):
    context = dict()

    PickupFormSet = modelformset_factory(PickUp, fields='__all__', form=PickupForm)
    qs = PickUp.objects.filter(deleted=False).prefetch_related('status')

    context['pickupformset'] = PickupFormSet(queryset=qs)

    return render(request, "index.html", context)
```

This is part of the template:

```
{% for pickup in pickupformset %}
{% if pickup.id.value %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ pickup.id }}{{pickup.deleted}}</td>
    <td>{{pickup.name}}{{pickup.name.value}}</td>
    <td>{{pickup.status}}</td>
</tr>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Each record displayed triggers a database query to get the status description.

```
SELECT `frontend_status`.`id`, `frontend_status`.`status_code`, `frontend_status`.`description` FROM `frontend_status`
```

Do you know why or how I can prevent this?

Comment: No, it does not solve this.

Comment: I believe the reason its queried is to construct the forms fields. Not sure how you may fix this though

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15203207/prevent-django-from-querying-for-foreignkey-options-for-every-form-in-modelforms). In Django 1.9+ I would try overriding [`form_kwargs`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/formsets/#passing-custom-parameters-to-formset-forms) instead of `_construct_forms`.

Comment: I was searching for something like the question you suggested but could not find such. Thank you very much, I will look into what is suggested!